# Tits' field of 1 element philosophy for $G_2$

Tags: lie-groups, finite-fields, algebraic-groups

It was my understanding that taking the formula for the number of elements in a finite group of Lie type over a field with $q$ elements (expressed as a function of $q$) and substituting $q = 1$, we will obtain the number of elements of the corresponding Weyl group. However the Wikipedia page on $G_2$ tells me that the finite group $G_2(q)$ has $q^6(q^6-1)(q^2-1)$ elements. It is not hard to see that when substituting $q = 1$ in this polynomial we obtain a number that is far from the 'correct' answer of $12$. What am I missing?

Comment: One has to first divide this polynomial in q with the largest power of (q-1) which divides it. In this case one has to divide this polynomial by $(q-1)^2$.

Comment: @random That does indeed solve the mystery, but where does this come from? Do you have a reference explaining this in more detail?

Comment: A google search gives that an idea is given on page 2 of this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.3824.pdf

Comment: Great, thank you! Turns out I know the author. Perhaps I should have asked him directly...

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. If you post the link as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Aha! I am sure he would be happy to go into details of the outlined proof.